# Macro Wildcard Search and copy entire row to sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge list I need to work on it it may have over 150k rows to be worked 
The data may be Like this

```
alimentdsk  2   2   2
aaaa        2   2   2
aaaa        2   2   2
asd         1   1   1
fal         1   1   1
d aliment t 1   1   1
```

Now I need all the rows that contain *aliment* to be copied to another sheet.

I have been trying this code but it copies all the rows

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim objMyUniqueArray As Object
    Dim lngMyArrayCounter As Long
    Dim lngMyRow As Long
    Dim varMyItem As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set objMyUniqueArray = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rngCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If InStr(rngCell, "aliment") > 0 Then
            If Not objMyUniqueArray.Exists(Trim(Cells(rngCell.Row, "C"))) Then
                lngMyArrayCounter = lngMyArrayCounter + 1
                objMyUniqueArray.Add (Trim(Cells(rngCell.Row, "C"))), lngMyArrayCounter
                varMyItem = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rngCell.Row, "C")
                For lngMyRow = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngMyRow, "C") = varMyItem Then
                        Rows(lngMyRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                    End If
                Next lngMyRow
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Set objMyUniqueArray = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MsgBox "All applicable rows have been copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Any help would be apriciated :)

Comment: Clarify, please, what exactly you want to do? Just copy all rows where cell in column `A` contains `aliment`? Or you have some additional requirements on column `C` (I've seen it from your code)? If yes, what they are? Btw, what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use the built in filter. if you're just looking at one column its super simple. I don't know what version you havem but in 2010 its data tab, then filter button. you'll see all columns have a drop down arrow on them. Go to the column you want, click the arrow, hover over "Text filters" in the drop list, then in the popout click "Contains". it'll pop up a small window, it'll show the column header, and you can change the option from contains, starts with, ends with, whatever.. and then the criteria you type what to look for. so your case you'd leave it as contains, and you'd type in "Aliment" in the critera. it will now only how every row that has that value in that column. You can then simply press ctrl + A which will select all visible rows, press ctrl + C to copy, (or ctrl + X to cut) select your sheet, go to the bottom, and paste in column 1 at the bottom of the data, bam. done.

To make that a macro, you do something like:

```
Sub Macro6()

   'Macro6 Macro



    Dim rng As Range

    Dim numrows As Long
    Dim numcols As Long

    numrows = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).column 'finds number of rows
    numrows = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).column ' finds number of columns

    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(numrows, numColumns)) 'gets all cells

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$7725").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*aliment*", Operator:=xlAnd 'this applies filter. *NOTE: change number after "field" to the number of the column

    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'after filter, this gets only visible cells (cells matching filter critera)
    rng.Copy 'copy rng

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select 'select appropriate sheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste  'paste
End Sub
```

That's a rough, sketch you may need to adapt it a smidge, it'll be SO MUCH faster than going row by row in a for loop.